# Updating relations in Linq To SQL is possible?

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql, primary-key

I need some functionality in my project and I don't know if its possible.
Here is a pic with the relations:

[image: i need to update the keys relation table LessonByFacultyMember and the same keys in Scheduling table]

I need to update the keys relation table LessonByFacultyMember and the same keys in Scheduling table.
I mean the keys LessonNumber,LessonCoursenumber,FacultyMemberId (LessonByFacultyMember table)
and LessonNumber,CourseNumber,FacultyMemberId (Scheduling Table).

Is it possible to update this kind of relations?

UPDATE:

I just want to be clear that i mean the possibility to change the VALUE that stored in the keys dynamically in some method.

Comment: I think you need to update the keys in the database and drag those tables again in the dbml file.

Comment: probably i am not clear, i want to edit the values that saved in the key dynamicly in the application not the key in the dbml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do so by selecting Update Cascade option in Foreign key  in the database.This options automatically updates the key values in the other tables. But in your case this is not needed. The table LessonByFacultyMember should have a column LessonByFacultyMemberId as a primary key and that should be in the Scheduling table as a Reference instead of putting all the three columns in the Scheduling table. If you do so ,you don't need to worry about the updating LessonNumber,CourseNumber,FacultyMemberId in the Scheduling Table. Also in your Scheduling table there should be a column SchedulingID as a Primary Key. You can take LessonByFacultyMemberId ,SchedulingID  as an auto incremented integer. Also there is no need to make LessonNumber,CourseNumber,FacultyMemberId as a Primary key in the LessonByFacultyMember  table. Instead you need to make them as unique key. Similarly in Scheduling table make the current primary key as unique key and have SchedulingId as primary key. In case of showing records you need to make select statement using joins and it is better to create a view for such statement. In case if still it is  not clear , create a sqlFiddle on http://sqlfiddle.com/  for your schema and share that in your question or comment to this answer. I will update the same.

Comment: thank you very much Priyank, but as i learned many to many relation contains the primay key of the two tables. the relation table is on update cascade. scheduling table is also erlation table between LessonByFacultyMember and TimeTable. and sorry i didnt succeed t ocreate sqlFiddle